# Multithreading not using full processor/memory/disk capacity

Tags: python, multithreading

My Python code is to exctract information from XML files and load it into a database.
These files named as numbers `11582.xml`, `5300593.xml`, etc.
and I have around 1 million files.

I have built the code and it is working fine.
I faced a problem that the code does not take full processor/memory/disk capacity.
My processor should 20% max used.

I asked here and other places and found that I have to use multithread to use full capacity.
So I have to change my script to adopt multithreading.
I did that but still not working to the max.

What I did wrong? and how to fix it?

My code:

```
import pymssql
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import thread
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=Server123;'
                      'Database=NLP;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')


cursor = conn.cursor()

def ExtractData(ThreadName):
    for file in glob.glob("H:\\datas_Output\\xmldata\\" & ThreadName & "*.xmi"):

        filename = file[24:-8]
        tree = ET.parse(file)
        root = tree.getroot()

        for Tag in ['Kitkat', 'Snickers', 'Bounty']:
            iTag = '{textsem.ecore}' + Tag
            for country in root.findall(iTag):
                XMIID = country.get('{XMI}id')
                sofa = country.get('sofa')
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Tags (filename,tag,xmiid,sofa) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", filename, Tag, XMIID, sofa)



try:
   thread.start_new_thread( ExtractData, ("1") )
   thread.start_new_thread( ExtractData, ("2") )
except:
   print("Error: unable to start thread")

conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not generate the list of files and then process them with a pool?

```
import multiprocessing

def ExtractData(file):
    filename = file[24:-8]
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for Tag in ['Kitkat', 'Snickers', 'Bounty']:
        iTag = '{textsem.ecore}' + Tag
        for country in root.findall(iTag):
            XMIID = country.get('{XMI}id')
            sofa = country.get('sofa')
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Tags (filename,tag,xmiid,sofa) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", filename, Tag, XMIID, sofa)

# if there are millions of files, you might want an iterator
filename_iterator = glob.iglob("H:/datas_Output/xmldata/", recursive=True)

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
    results = pool.map(ExtractData, filename_iterator)
```

Comment: will that make it use all processors cores?

Comment: @asmgx: It will use up to `cpu_count()` cores if your system has them.

Comment: @Eric: For compatibility with Windows the part from `# if there are millions...` onward should be inside an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard.

Comment: It never goes to the function ExtractData !

Comment: still does not go to ExtractData ! I changed pool.map function to have ExtractData yet it nevers reach there

Answer (score 0):

Python multithreading isn't "real". For one thing, there's a "Global Interpreter Lock" (GIL) that only allows one thread to run py at the same time. Also, python threads don't use independent real processor cores. The main benefit is one thread may be blocked on external I/O operations; the other threads can do something.

However, in other environments such as JVMs (Java, Kotlin etc.) real threads are supported.